# Java Method runs after condition is complete

Tags: java

I made this CLI code that will let you Log in with a preset username and password. Everything seems to work accept one crucial detail. For some reason when I run the code, it will prompt the username and password question (As it should) but even after I put a successful login and it displays "Login Successful, welcome Example1" it will reprompt the Username and Password questions. I don't know how to fix this.

```
class Main {
  static String Username = "Example1";
  static String Password = "Example2";
  static Scanner InfoCheck = new Scanner(System.in);
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(LoginAttempt() == true) {
      System.out.println("Login Successful, welcome " + Username);
    }
    
    while(LoginAttempt() != true) {
      LoginAttempt();
    }
  }
  public static boolean LoginAttempt() {
    System.out.println("Enter your Username:");
    String UsernameAttempt = InfoCheck.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter your Password:");
    String PasswordAttempt = InfoCheck.nextLine();

    if(UsernameAttempt.equals(Username) && PasswordAttempt.equals(Password)) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("Incorrect Username or Password");
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried making it a while loop that will repeat while the Login variable is set to false, but even when set to true it will reprompt the question. I also tried making it a while true loop that leads to an if, else statement that will check if the variable is true or false.

Comment: Every time you write `LoginAttempt()` in your code that means that method will be called and everything inside it executed until a return is hit (or an exception thrown).  So `if(LoginAttempt() == true)` will ask the user for input of his name and then `while(LoginAttempt() != true)` will call the method again at least once and ask the user for his input name again.

Comment: you are calling loginAttempt again, what did you expect will happen?

Comment: Remove the first if block and move the success message at the end.
Also "!= true" is strange, just write "!" in front or "== false"

Comment: In general, to fix your behaviour all the code in the main method could simply reduced to `while(!LoginAttempt()); System.out.println("Login Successful, welcome " + Username);` Just one simple loop that asks the user for input until the method returns true and then the printing of the success message once the loop is done.

Comment: Variable names should begin in lowercase, so they don't get confused with class names, which start in uppercase. Also, [naming convention suggest](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) that method names should start in lowercase as well, so it should be `loginAttempt()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(LoginAttempt() == true) {
      System.out.println("Login Successful, welcome " + Username);
    }
    
    while(LoginAttempt() != true) {
      LoginAttempt();
    }
```

You call `LoginAttempt` first in the `if` and whatever is the result call again `LoginAttempt` in the `while`, so at least twice.

Rewrite it as:

```
boolean attemptOk = false;
do {
    attemptOk = LoginAttempt();
} while ( !attemptOk );
System.out.println("Login successfull!");
```

Aside note that method names should follow the lower camel case rule: `loginAttempt` and not `LoginAttempt`.

Comment: @user85421 first may trouble OP with empty body, second is more problematic as message would be dispatched internally and externally to the call. But ok to me.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... it will reprompt the Username and Password questions. I don't know how to fix this. ..."*

The code for the *main* method is incorrect.

You're calling *LoginAttempt* too often.

```java
if(LoginAttempt() == true) {
    System.out.println("Login Successful, welcome " + Username);
}

while(LoginAttempt() != true) {
    LoginAttempt();
}
```

> *"... I tried making it a while loop that will repeat while the Login variable is set to false ..."*

In this case, only call *LoginAttempt* once, from the *while-loop*'s *code-block*, or from the *conditional-statement*.
I recommend the former.

```java
boolean exit;
do exit = LoginAttempt(); 
while (!exit);
```

Or

```java
while (!LoginAttempt()) {
        
}
```

On a final note, you can refine the *LoginAttempt* method.

```java
public static boolean LoginAttempt() {
    System.out.println("Enter your Username:");
    if (!InfoCheck.nextLine().equals(Username))
        System.out.println("Incorrect Username");
    else {
        System.out.println("Enter your Password:");
        if(InfoCheck.nextLine().equals(Password)) return true;
        else System.out.println("Incorrect Password");
    }
    return false;
}
```